# Android SDKCONTROLLER app (Sensor Emulation)

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, multi-touch, android-sensors

looked everywhere but no one had an answer to this sadly.

Been trying to use an android app that comes with the Android development tools called SDKcontroller. This app is suppose to let me test the multi touch capabilities of my apps. This app is suppose to send input information from a real android device to the emulator. It should let me control the emulator by using the touch sensor in my android device.

I fallowed the instruction and the app is telling me that is connected to the emulator but that is as far as i get. I can touch and touch all I want but the emulator is not responding.

Has somebody been able to get this to work? If so please let me know.

here is a link to the you tube video demonstrating the app: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Erd2k6EKxCQ

here is the android project site: http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation